# Technology used in VLC rtsp over http

Tags: vlc, http-live-streaming

I am using apple dispatch to make a rstp over http tunneling module and using vlc as a client from testing. I am not able to test it and getting this error log

```
main debug: processing request item rtsp://192.168.36.41/http_str_cgi.exe node Playlist skip 0
main debug: resyncing on rtsp://192.168.36.41/http_str_cgi.exe
main debug: rtsp://192.168.36.41/http_str_cgi.exe is at 0
main debug: starting new item
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for 'rtsp://192.168.36.41/http_str_cgi.exe'
main debug: thread (input) created at priority 1 (../.././src/input/input.c:214)
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
main debug: thread started
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
main debug: using timeshift path 'C:\Users\in0016\AppData\Local\Temp'
main debug: `rtsp://192.168.36.41/http_str_cgi.exe' gives access `rtsp' demux `' path `192.168.36.41/http_str_cgi.exe'
main debug: creating demux: access='rtsp' demux='' path='192.168.36.41/http_str_cgi.exe'
main debug: looking for access_demux module: 1 candidate
live555 debug: DESCRIBE failed with 0: Failed to read response: No error
live555 debug: connection timeout
live555 error: Failed to connect with rtsp://192.168.36.41/http_str_cgi.exe
main debug: no access_demux module matching "rtsp" could be loaded
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 60005.003 ms - Total 60005.003 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 60005.000 ms)
main debug: creating access 'rtsp' path='192.168.36.41/http_str_cgi.exe'
main debug: looking for access module: 1 candidate
main debug: net: connecting to 192.168.36.41 port 554
main debug: connection succeeded (socket = 1440)
access_realrtsp debug: rtsp connected
access_realrtsp warning: only real/helix rtsp servers supported for now
main debug: no access module matching "rtsp" could be loaded
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 215.000 ms - Total 215.000 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 215.000 ms)
main debug: waitpipe: object killed
main error: open of `rtsp://192.168.36.41/http_str_cgi.exe' failed: (null)
main debug: thread ended
main debug: dead input
main debug: thread times: real 1m0.257589s, kernel 0m0.015600s, user 0m0.000000s
main debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
main debug: nothing to play
qt4 debug: IM: Deleting the input
main debug: TIMER input launching for 'rtsp://192.168.36.41/http_str_cgi.exe' : 60320.003 ms - Total 60320.003 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 60320.000 ms)
```

Has used apple dispatch to implement rtsp over http or they has used some other technology. If they are using apple dispatch then it must [send first a GET request and then a POST request](http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/icefloe/dispatch028.html). But it is not behaving this way.

VLC version : 1.1.3 and tried on 1.1.5 too. same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, VLC does not support Apple's proprietary rtsp over http protocol.
You should use Quicktime Player as client software instead.